# settings file can not be updated without recompiling

Tags: c#, settings.settings

I have a settings file in my C# windows application. In the settings designer, i created an entry for a string value and an entry for bool value. After i deploy the project in debug directory, and i change the value of bool entry in `[appName].exe.config file`. But i see that there is no change in that value in my application. 
Lets be clear. i have a checkbox in my windows form. And i have `CheckBoxInitValue` in my settings file. `CheckBoxInitValue` is **False** default. When i change it to **True** in `[appName].exe.config` file and rerun the application, the checkbox initial state remains unchecked. It should be checked initially. Because i set the checkbox value in form load event by the following code:

```
myCheckbox.Checked = mySettingFileName.Default.CheckBoxInitValue;
```

How can i update the the properties in settings file in configuration file so that i can use new values without the need of compiling?
**Edit: (.exe.config usersettings part)**

```
<userSettings>
    <WPortFWDownloader.ayarlarFWDownloader>
        <setting name="MyStringValue" serializeAs="String">
            <value>My Default Value</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="CheckBoxInitValue" serializeAs="String">
            <value>False</value>
        </setting>
    </WPortFWDownloader.ayarlarFWDownloader>
</userSettings>
```

Comment: How about we see your config code ? it should be updating from the config file without needing to recompile

Comment: Hello. Let me mention that if the value type is a string, i can change the value within config file. But if it is a bool type, i can not change the value in config file. It seems strange.

Comment: so the string value is working ?

Comment: yes, string value is working but bool value is not. When i change the bool value CheckBoxInitValue, it does not give any effect without recompiling.

Comment: Can I see the code that actually reads the config ?

Comment: hi, this is the code i get value of bool value. i mentioned in my question too. **myCheckbox.Checked = mySettingFileName.Default.CheckBoxInitValue;** and i edited my question showing the inside of .exe.config file. Remember that i change the value in that .exe.config file, but it does not affect the application settings. But i works well for string values. That means when i change a value of a string entry in .exe.config, i can see the value changed in application settings.

Comment: This was an interesting problem and it has been solved by moving project folder to another path. strange right?